# Pecl uuid error (uuid_make() is not a function)

Tags: php, uuid

I've install UUID using pecl and then i add the extension to php.ini.
The extension is correctly loaded but i get the error

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function uuid_make()

This is my code :

```
<?php

$uuid = v4();
echo $uuid;


function v4() {   
  $context = $uuid = null;  
  uuid_create($context);  

  uuid_make($context, UUID_MAKE_V4);  
  uuid_export($context, UUID_FMT_STR, $uuid);  
  return trim($uuid);  
}

?>
```

Why i'm getting this error? 
If i print the list of available function i don't have neither uuid_make and uuid_export.
Hi search around the web but i always find someone who use uuid_make and uuid_export.
I can't find documentation about this module.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `uuid_make` and `uuid_export` are from the OSSP uuid extension, which is completely different from the PECL extension (although they both have a function named `uuid_create`).

The PECL extension has very little documentation and several limitations (at least from what I can tell scanning the source, e.g., no support for UUID V5). The OSSP extension is complete but must be installed from source.

If you only need to occasionally generate UUIDs, one simple alternative could be installing a uuid utility (e.g., `apt-get install uuid`) then use something like `exec`.

Comment: PECL uuid is a _thin_ wrapper around libuuid: check [its documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid) for a reference to the PECL UUID library's functions.